# How to convert UTC datetime (string) into the visitors timezone?

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

How to convert a date like this: `2012-07-16 01:00:00 +00` (it's in the `UTC +00:00` timezone) to the visitors timezone in Javascript, ensuring that daylight saving will be handelled correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break it into parts and use [Date.UTC](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.4.3), e.g.

```
function fromUTC(s) {
  s = s.split(/[-: ]/g);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(+s[0], --s[1], +s[2], +s[3], +s[4], +s[5], 0));
}

var s = '2012-07-16 01:00:00 +00';

alert(fromUTC(s));
```